# Netgear M4300: Is it possible to enable multiple destination ports for mirroring?

Tags: switching, monitoring, netgear-prosafe

I have a Netgear m4300 12x12f. Using the web Console I'm able to use one global port for mirroring traffic from other ports. Is there a way to have different ports mirroring different traffic? I'm open to changing the firmware on the switch if that could fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Most switches that can mirror have a limitation of one or two mirroring sessions. You should be able to get differentiated views of the traffic in the application that you use on the device that receives the mirrored traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have up to 4 monitor session with different sources / mirroring ports

I happen to have a m4300 12x12f and was able to test it:

```
(XXX-R2) (Config)#monitor session 1 source interface 1/0/19
(XXX-R2) (Config)#monitor session 1 destination interface 1/0/20
(XXX-R2) (Config)#monitor session 2 destination interface 1/0/22
(XXX-R2) (Config)#monitor session 2 source interface 1/0/21

(Config)#show running-config | include monitor

monitor session 1 destination interface 1/0/20
monitor session 1 source interface 1/0/19
monitor session 2 destination interface 1/0/22
monitor session 2 source interface 1/0/21
```

.

```
(Config)#monitor session ?

<1-4>                    Session number.
```

I run version 12.0.7.7

Comment: This looks great, I'm guessing sessions run in parallel? How did you set up this config

Comment: The first four lines are the commands I typed in the CLI.